# Passing Key/Value data to PHP on Command-Line using Powershell variable

Tags: php, powershell, command-line

I have a PHP file that runs on Windows command line, using PowerShell. I can pass in an "associative array" to the file, like so:

```
php .\my_file.php --first="eke" --second="orie" --third="ubochi afor" --fourth="nkwo"
```

To inspect the arguments within `my_file.php`, one can use the following:

```
print_r($argv);
Array
(
    [0] => .\schedule_mail.php
    [1] => --first=eke
    [2] => --second=orie
    [3] => --third=ubochi afor
    [4] => --fourth=nkwo
)

print_r(getopt(null, ['first:', 'second:', 'third:', 'fourth:']));
Array
(
    [first] => eke
    [second] => orie
    [third] => ubochi afor
    [fourth] => nkwo
)
```

This all works well until I replace the passed in data with a variable like so:

```
$Var = '--first="eke" --second="orie" --third="ubochi afor" --fourth="nkwo"'
php .\my_file.php $Var
```

In this latter case, here is what I get instead:

```
print_r($argv);
Array
(
    [0] => .\schedule_mail.php
    [1] => --first=eke --second=orie --third=ubochi
    [2] => afor --fourth=nkwo
)


print_r(getopt(null, ['first:', 'second:', 'third:', 'fourth:']));
Array
(
    [first] => eke --second=orie --third=ubochi
)
```

How can I effectively pass this data to the PHP file?

Comment: @Paxz, as a matter of fact, I already figured out exactly what you suggest, and it did work out fine. If you would make this an answer, I'd mark it accepted.

Comment: Sure, wrote an answer. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `$Var = '--first="eke" --second="orie" --third="ubochi afor" --fourth="nkwo"'` didn't work, was because you made `$Var` one big string.

Thisway what you actually parsed to the file was something like this:

```
php .\my_file.php '--first="eke" --second="orie" --third="ubochi afor" --fourth="nkwo"'
```

Powershell interprets this not as multiple parameters to the file, but as one.

---

What you need to do instead, is make `$Var` an array:

```
$Var = @('--first="eke"', '--second="orie"', '--third="ubochi afor"', '--fourth="nkwo"')
php .\my_file.php $Var
```

This way Powershell interprets every entry of the array as one unique parameter to the file.

Comment: Well, what is playing out here is the delicate interaction between Powershell and the PHP command line client. So PS is providing the data for PHP to interpret. By the way, the array variable declaration will also go well WITHOUT those parenthesis, like so: `$Var = '--first="eke"', '--second="orie"', '--third="ubochi afor"', '--fourth="nkwo"'`

Comment: `$Var = '--first="eke"', '--second="orie"', '--third="ubochi afor"', '--fourth="nkwo"'` creates the same as `@('--first="eke"', '--second="orie"', '--third="ubochi afor"', '--fourth="nkwo"')`. I just preferre the using `@()` to clarify the use of an array :)

Answer (score -2):

Might be this could help. You can check here -

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php